Renovate with Maven CI friendly versions
We use Maven CI Friendly Versions for our multi-module Maven pom.xml files.
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
    <version>18</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.ci</groupId>
  <artifactId>ci-parent</artifactId>
  <name>First CI Friendly</name>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  ...
  <properties>
    <revision>DEVELOP-SNAPSHOT</revision>
  </properties>
</project>

In addition, we use renovate to keep the dependencies of the projects up to date.
With this setup, renovate tries to update the revision property of the project to be checked, which is not desired. For example, when running renovate for the development branch, a merge request is created that tries to update the revision property to the latest release version of the same multi-module build repository.
The only solution that might work is to exclude all artifactIds or groupIds of the same project from the renovate-config of the multi-maven-module build.
Here is an example for the problem.

Isn't there a suppression in renovate to suppress the upgrade of the property? Furthermore is that the whole setup for CI friendly?

Is ${revision} used elsewhere? Because I don't think Renovate even checks if the current project version needs update usually, sounds strange.

You might want to open a reproduction case on Renovate's GitHub otherwise.

I will make a reproduction case on Github, yes.

I can see the difference now between projects like apache commons and initializr which work and our projects which doesn't work. The others are not releasing the <packaging>pom</packaging> modules, but use maven-deploy-plugin with the configuration to skip. Those modules are the ones which make renovate problems according to the debug logs. For normal dependencies or jar packaging modules there are no problems, but because of those pom packaging modules renovate whats to change the revision variable.

This is an example for the behaviour https://github.com/a-nickol/maven-it-extension/pull/3

Please share the link to the GH discussion when open, it'll help future readers of this post :)

https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/29299

It looks like this is a workaround exists, won't fix problem. :-(
